# Making Chameitz Hefker on Shabbat

Tags: shabbat, halacha-theory, passover, chametz-leaven

This year, because Erev Pesach is on Shabbat, the completion of the burning (done on Friday, after a search on Thursday night), is the second (slightly expanded) recitation of the Kol Chamira on Shabbat morning. The initial recitation, after the search declares the remaining Chameitz hefker, ownerless, but this cannot be a complete renunciation as one is still allowed to own and even eat Chameitz until the morning of Erev Pesach.

According to many opinions that I read [here](https://www.dafdigest.org/masechtos/Eruvin/Eruvin%20071.pdf), it is permissible to make an item hefker/ownerless on Shabbat, so the fuller renunciation would not present a problem. But one opinion on the linked page reads

[image: reads]

How, then, would someone following this opinion complete the nullification of Chameitz in a year when the first Seder is Saturday night, while still eating Chameitz for the meals on Shabbat?

Comment: You declare it null. Your sources are about making something ownerless. Shulchan Aruch 432:2 says אחר הבדיקה ומיד בלילה יבטלנו, ויאמר: "כל חמירא דאיתיה ברשותי דלא חזיתיה ודלא ביערתיה - ליבטיל וליהוי כעפרא דארעא

Comment: In order to declare something ownerless you have to do it in front of three people. (Choshen Mishpat 273:7)

Comment: Another case of declaring something null is if you put straw on your sukkah floor to make it less than 20 cubits tall, you have to declare the straw null to the floor. https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%9C%D7%92_%D7%93

Comment: so would the answer be "one would use a text that does not include the phrase ולהוי הפקר"?

Comment: @DoubleAA `in front of three people` I read (Meiri Magen Avot 18) that this restriction is only for land (although I admit that I don't know much about this sugya).

Answer (score 3):

This question assumes that *bittul Chametz* is a form of *hefker*. This is indeed the position of some Rishonim (see Tosfos Pesachim 4).

This very question is one of seven questions posed by the [Ramban (Pesachim 4b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Chiddushei_Ramban_on_Pesachim.4b.1?lang=bi) on the position of Tosfos that *bittul Chametz* is a form of *hefker*.

> לפיכך פירשו בשם ר"ת ז"ל דמה שאמרו בביטול בעלמא סגי משום דביטול היינו
> הפקר ונפקא להו היתירא משום שנאמר לך שלך אי אתה רואה אבל אתה רואה כו'
> וזה אינו שלו. זהו דעת רבותינו הצרפתים ז"ל בביטול.
> ...
> ועוד קשה לי **שהתירו ביטול בשבת** כדתניא מבטלו בלבו אחד שבת ואחד י"ט ו**הלא הפקר נראה שאסור לאדם להפקיר נכסיו בשבת** כענין ששנינו אין מקדישין ואין כו' גזירה משום מקח וממכר.

The Ramban (see continuation there) uses this is one of his proofs that *bittul* is fundamentally different to *hefker*.

See [Magen Avos](https://hebrewbooks.org/1755) (written by the [Meiri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menachem_Meiri)) who defends the position of Tosfos.

For further discussion about the prohibition to be *mafkir* on Shabbos, see the Responsa of the [Shoel uMeishiv (V1,21.2)](https://www.sefaria.org/Shoel_uMeshiv_Mahadura_VI.21.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

Comment: Does the Ramban's text of the bitul include a phrase like ולהוי הפקר?